# select rows where column > percentile(column, 0.5) in hive

Tags: hive, aggregate, percentile

I want to select rows where the value of certain column, say A, is larger than its p50 over whole data. So I write such SQL in hive as follow:

```sql
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict;
with temp_table as (
    select percentile(A, 0.5) as p50
    from my_table
)
select 
    my_table.A
    from my_table, temp_table
    where my_table.A > temp_table.p50
```

But the process is hanging. Is the SQL correct? Or is there better way to do this task?

Comment: how big the table is?

Comment: @zealous around 1million rows. Does it matter ? Since the output of `temp_table` is only one row in my opinion.